# Error: Invalid request for adding product to quote

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to Add Products to Cart with respect to customer (programmatically) but getting error "Invalid request for adding product to quote". I have both Simple products (with custom options) and configurable products. Below is my code. Please help. Many thanks in advance.

```
public function addtocartAction(){
    try {
        $cusId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cusId');
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($cusId);
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);
        $quoteId = $quote->getId();
        //$products = $this->getRequest()->getParam('products');
        $products = json_decode('[{"proId": "906","proQty": "1", "options":{"17":"wq","16":"18"}}]');

        foreach($products as $product) {
            /*if (!$product->getId()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }*/
            foreach ($product->options as $optKey => $optValue) {
                $optAll[$optKey] = $optValue;
            }

            $mainProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->proId);
            $params = array(
                'product' => $product->proId,
                'qty'     => $product->proQty,
                'options' => $optAll
            );
            echo "<pre />"; print_r($params);
            $quote->addProduct($mainProduct, $params);
            $quote->setIsActive(1);
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }
        $rslt['success'] = '1';
        $rslt['message'] = 'Product has been succefully added to cart';
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $rslt['success'] = '0';
        $rslt['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    print_r(json_encode($rslt));

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$params` should be in Varien_Object when you used quote object.

Try this following

```
$request = new Varien_Object($params);
$quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($_product, $request);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add onto pilathraj's answer, the error

> Invalid request for adding product to quote

Come from **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php** from around line 965

```
public function addProductAdvanced(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $request = null, $processMode = null)
    {
...

if (!($request instanceof Varien_Object)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invalid request for adding product to quote.'));

...
}
```

For the testing code that i'm using to add to the cart, this is what it looks like and what pilathraj's suggestion fixed:

```
$productId = 906;
$params = array(
     'product' => $productId,
     'qty' => 1,
 );
$request = new Varien_Object($params);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
    $quote->addProduct($product, $request);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();
}
```